# How to truncate HWND title

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a window which opens to a dynamic title.  I would like to have the window's title truncate if the window is resized and there isn't room to show the full title.

For example, I have

```
HWND handle = GetHWND(); // gets me the correct handle
std::wstring title = L"some fairly long window title";
SetWindowTextW(handle, title.c_str());
```

Is there either a way to truncate the HWND title automatically or alternately a way to get the pixel width of the title text so I can set the title manually if the window shrinks?

Comment: Huh?  What happens to *your* window's text when you make it smaller?

Comment: Should have made it more clear.  I want the window text to truncate based on the title size (it may in fact have enough room to be longer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the width of a string drawn to a given device context (HDC) by means of the [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the text via `SetWindowText`, respond to `WM_GETTEXT.` The two are related: DefWindowProc responds to WM_GETTEXT by returning the value you set earlier with SetWindowText.

Now when you receive the WM_GETTEXT message you can return a text that's appropriate at that moment, taking the current width into account.